# verificar email em jquery como se fossem duas string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, regex

Boa noite, estou finalizando uma verificação de formulário e travei em um ponto, talvez pela maneira que escreveram o código do meu trabalho não consigo usar `jquery validate`, então tenho problemas para verificar se um campo de `input` tem um e-mail digitado.

Fiz um código de validação que conta os caracteres:

```js
//verifica email
    $("#txtEmail").blur(function() {
        if ($("#txtEmail").val().length < 10) {
            $("#txtEmail").css('background', '#fb4745');
            $("#alertEmail").show('fast')
            $("#alertEmail").text('Preencha o campo com um email valido');  

        }
        if ($("#txtEmail").val().length >= 10) {
            $("#txtEmail").css('background', '#6ebe51'); 
            $("#alertEmail").hide('fast');
        } 
    });
```

Minha duvida é: tem como fazer um código que detecte se o campo de email é formado por uma string + @ + string?
Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu costumo usar uma regex assim `[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+`.
A ideia é:

- `[^@]+` N caracteres que não `@`
- uma vez `@`
- de novo N caracteres que não `@`
- uma vêz ponto (pode haver mais dentro de `[^@]+`, mas aqui obriga a que haja pelo menos 1
- de novo `[^@]+`

No teu caso ficaria assim:

```
if ($("#txtEmail").val().match(/[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+/)) {
   // etc...
}
```

Exemplo:

```js
var testes = [
  'email@gmail.com', 'falsomail(at)gmail.com'
];

testes.forEach(teste => {
  const match = teste.match(/[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+/);
  console.log(teste, match ? 'válido' : 'inválido');
});
```

Comment: Muito bom!! Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Talvez, `<input type="email" .. />` também resolva.

Comment: Eu tentei, mas provavelmente a maneira como escreveram o código dava erro. Então achei mais fácil contornar isso do que procurar a causa em todo o documento e acabar modificando algo que dependia desse "erro no código"